# Nest param received by pipe

Tags: nestjs

so while developping a simple REST endpoints using `nestjs`, i have found a little problem.

I Have a pipe named `JoiValidationPipe` that validate the body of a request using a Joi object. everything is working but i have an issue if the request contain both body and a param :

```js
    @Patch(':id')
      @UsePipes(new JoiValidationPipe(CreateComicSchema))
      async updateComic(@Body() comic: Comic, @Param() params) {
        comic.id = params.id;
        return await this.comicService.update(comic);
      }
```

here the param received by JoiValidationPipe is just the `id` in request url, not the body.

I want to know if its possible to force the Pipe to receive the body of the request.

this problem do no exist if there is no parameter in the url, the `JoiValidatinPipe` automaticly receive the body.

**Create Comic**

```js
      @Post()
      @UsePipes(new JoiValidationPipe(CreateComicSchema))
      async createComic(@Body() comic: Comic) {
        return await this.comicService.create(comic);
      }
```

**JoiValidationPipe**

```js
    import * as Joi from 'joi';
    import { PipeTransform, Injectable, ArgumentMetadata, BadRequestException } from '@nestjs/common';

    @Injectable()
    export class JoiValidationPipe implements PipeTransform {
      constructor(private readonly schema) {}

      transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {

        const { error } = Joi.validate(value, this.schema);
        if (error) {
          throw new BadRequestException('Validation failed');
        }
        return value;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best use of `Pipes` to validate only some specifics types of parameters (among `Body`, `Param`, etc) is to give a class (or instance) as a parameter of these decorators.

e.g.

```
async updateComic(@Body(new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true }) comic: Comic, @Param() params) {
```

here, the pipe is only applied to `@Body`. But I did not use `@UsePipes` as this is not required/desired.